# Excel: Edit Column A if Column B equals value

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in my excel file. Column A is numeric values and Column B is units (kg/g). I need to convert all values to g (like in column c). Here's an example:

```
A        B     C
0.75     kg    750.00
0.80     kg    800.00
700.00   g     700.00
500.00   g     500.00
```

I was looking at VBA scripts but since I haven't used them before I'm not able to edit them to my needs at all. Any ideas?

Comment: why use vba? Put this in C1:    =IF(B2="kg", A2, A2/1000)

Comment: Also your example makes no sense, how does 500g = 700kg??

Comment: @tompreston - that's a special supermarket software :)

Comment: @tompreston Where did I convert 500g to 700Kg?

Comment: @VeeK in the last line, which has now been edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't want to use VBA (and you shouldn't need to, really), the formula above from @tom_preston is *almost* correct.

In "C2", you can use the formula **=IF(B2="kg",A2*1000,A1)** and just copy it down the line.

Comment: I didn't knew you could do it without VBA. Thanks a lot man and to you too @tompreston

Answer (score 0):

If you want it written in VBA as the question above asked here is the code that would be placed in a worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cellChanged As Range, c As Range

Const myVal As String = "kg"

Set cellChanged = Intersect(Target, Columns("B"))

     If Not cellChanged Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In cellChanged
             If UCase( c.Value) = UCase(myVal) Then
                c.Offset(, 1).Value = c.Offset(, -1).Value / 1000
             else
                c.Offset(, 1).Value = vbnullstring
            End if
        Next
      End if
End Sub
```

How that helps have a great day!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as others have noted a simple formula is much better than the VBA script.